# Brain transference in Star Fluxx

Tags: fluxx

The card Brain Transference reads:

> You and a player of your choice switch seats at the table (leaving your hands). You each take over the other player's entire position in the game, as if you were in that position all along.
>   Your turn ends immediately. The person next in order from your original seat goes next unless that's you, in which case the player after your new seat goes next.

(Leaving your hands) wording in card description is unclear to me.
When I change seat, do I keep my hand of cards or also switch cards with my opponent?

Comment: "My cards" wording in your question is also unclear. I suppose you mean keepers and creepers?

Comment: In my mind, the way to clarify this card is to look at it as a whole. Pretend that you swapped your mind into your opponent's body, and your opponent's mind into yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cards currently in your hand are left on the table. The keepers and creepers in front of you are left where you were.

You take over your targets position in the game, and they assume yours.

Comment: Ok, so I get both my opponent keepers and also their hand of cards.

Comment: And their creepers.